# react native - Having static and dynamic elements in FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to create a FlatList somewhat like Twitter's Post Tweet list displaying options ranging from Camera to Photos in the Gallery of the device.

[image]

I'm not sure how to have first 2-3 elements as static elements and then add on dynamic elements via a CameraRoll or something.

The first solution that came to my mind was having an array with its first 2-3 elements as text containing "Camera", "Gallery" etc. and then concatenate that array with the dynamic array and handle everything via the renderItem() function to display different view for the "static element" case. But I'm hoping that there's a **better way** to do this. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Why not two components?

Comment: If you mean to have two lists, first for static elements and second for dynamic elements (Is that what you're talking about?), then the scrolling will work improperly. The "Static + Dynamic" list as a whole should be scrollable.

Comment: I see. Lack of react-native experience for me. Then if those two components would be in something like a container then scrolling won't work?

Comment: I don't think your idea of concatenating the "static" array with the "dynamic" array and then having some extra logic in `renderItem()` is bad. That's probably the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: @devserkan Scrolling works, but they'll have separate scrolling i.e. when you're gonna scroll the dynamic elements component, the static elements will stay there and the dynamic elements list will scroll within itself. I don't want to show them as two separate entities to the user.

Comment: @Tholle It's the easiest way to do in my mind right now but it sounds like a "way around". I'm pretty sure there would be a way available (for example: having them as two components, yet combined scrolling or something, I don't know how to achieve that though.)

Comment: Again, lack of react-native here. I understood that the container itself can't be scrollable here. Sorry getting in the middle of conversation. I hope you find a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best and easiest option is to do it the way you outlined: Concatenate the "static" array with the "dynamic" array, and treat the static ones separately.

**Example**

```
class Options extends React.Component {
  renderItem({ item, index }) {
    if (index === 0) {
      return <Camera />;
    } else if (index === 1) {
      return <Live />;
    } else {
      return <GeneralItem {...item} />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const statics = [{ text: 'Camera' }, { text: 'Live' }];

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={statics.concat(this.props.data)}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really wish there was a proper way to do it because this felt like a way around to me. Nevertheless, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using **ListHeaderComponent** prop inside FlatList.
We can put there any JSX and achieve static first item.

```
   <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({item, index})=><Item musicItem={item} index={index} currentIndex={currlistIndex} db_index={item.id_db}/>}
      extraData={currlistIndex}
      ListHeaderComponent={<AddSongs/>}             
    />
```

Comment: Using `ListFooderComponent` instead of `ListHeaderComponent` would address exactly the approach, that @Ketan Malhotra was asking for. This should be the correct answer imo.